# I am unable to access the Driver behavior service API's through any means like from node js, python, and by postman also

Tags: ibm-cloud, postman, iot-driver-behavior

I am using one API to get the car probe data by date. This is the API
get method: https://api.ibm.com/driverinsights/datastore/carProbe/dateList?tenant_id=1ce29c2a-d408-4551-b1fd-815cf5810a02

```
Headers:
accept:application/json
content-type:application/json
Authorization:Basic NEZwMkd5bVc6cEdddHVqc1c1eVJaQVA=
```

I am getting response as

```
{
    "httpCode": "404",
    "httpMessage": "Not Found",
    "moreInformation": "The requested URL was not found on this server"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the error message on your side says "404 Not Found".

Please check your hostname in the URL of Driver Behavior service.

[Correct]
"https://automotive.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/driverinsights"

[Incorrect (yours)]
"https://api.ibm.com/driverinsights"

Please refer to official API documentation. 
https://developer.ibm.com/api/view/id-261:title-IBM_Watson_IoT_Driver_Behavior#doc

Comment: The official doc is confusing - as note it is has automotive.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com full of references to api.ibm.com